# Extension method where and select not working

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting the following error on:

```
A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause
```

I am a little confused on why this is with using extension methods in linq, can anyone point me in the right direction? thanks!

**Code:**

```
 using (var db = new DB())
 {
   var result = from u in db.users
   .Where(u.username == txtUsername.Text && u.password == txtPassword.Text)
   .Select( a => new User
   {
     id = a.user_id,
     name = a.username,
     roleID = a.role_id
   })
  .ToList(); //error here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to mix both query and method syntax - remove the 'from u in users':

```
 using (var db = new DB())
 {
   var result = db.users
   .Where(u => u.username == txtUsername.Text && u.password == txtPassword.Text)
   .Select( a => new User
   {
     id = a.user_id,
     name = a.username,
     roleID = a.role_id
   })
  .ToList(); //error here
}
```

The u is declared within the lambda (u=>...) and is implicitly typed to user

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it just be

```
db.users.Where(u.username...
```

Instead of

```
from u in db.users
   .Where(u.username
```

You are trying to use both LINQ SQL like syntax and extension method